# error deserializing the object of type .... End element '......' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

When I deserialize my jsonstring ,I am getting error  message

```
 There was an error deserializing the object of type RecordInfo. End element 'Warning' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''.
```

This is my JsonString

```
public const string jsonString = @" 
        {
            ""RequestId"":514106,
            ""Warning"":[],
            ""CustomerData"": {
                ""Email"":""abc@abc.com"",
                ""FullName"":""OrTguOfE"",
                ""OrderData"":[]
            }
        }";
```

Data contracts

```
[DataContract]
    public class RecordInfo
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "RequestId")]
        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Warning")]
        public string Warning { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "CustomerData")]
        public CustomerData CustomerData { get; set; }
    }
 [DataContract]
    public class CustomerData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "FullName")]
        public string FullName  { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "OrderData")]
        public OrderData[]  OrderData { get; set; }
    }
[DataContract]
    public class OrderData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "OrderId")]
        public string OrderId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SourceId")]
        public string SourceId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SourceData")]
        public SourceData[] SourceData { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SourceData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "SourceDescription")]
        public string SourceDescription { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ProductName")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the Deserializer I use

```
private static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
```

When I deserialize the bove jsonstring ,I am getting error  message

```
 There was an error deserializing the object of type RecordInfo. End element 'Warning' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''.
```

Any suggestions to resolve this error?

Comment: which `DataMember(s)` do you want to be `Nullable`

Comment: @Wiemon What is "Warning" suppose to map to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `IsRequired = false`, e.g.:

```
[DataMember(Name = "RequestId", IsRequired = false)]
```

**MSDN Source**: [`DataMemberAttribute.IsRequired` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value that instructs the serialization engine that the
>   member must be present when reading or deserializing.

Comment: For my code I am getting an error message during deserialization There was an error deserializing the object of type RecordInfo. End element 'Warning' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else: you've declared `Warning` property as `string`, but your JSON contains an object: `""Warning"":[]`.

Comment: in case there is a "Warning":["WARNING_no data ForCustomer"] how my warning object should look like  if I create a datacontract like [DataContract(Name = "Warning")]
    public class Warning
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Message", IsRequired = false)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    } ,it wont return the message

Comment: Change your `Warning` property definition to be `string[]`: `public string[] Warning { get; set; }`

Comment: For my code i am getting following error {"There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'menu' from namespace ''."}

What should i do to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Another reason I found for the similar error is when we map an array type of Json field to a non array field of the data contract class. (e.g.) my JSON data was like -

```
"ipAddress": [
    "10.61.255.25",
    "fe80:0000:0000:0000:10e1:0b66:96a6:9ac8"
]
```

But because I was unaware of this type of `IPAddress` data, I was mapping `ipaddress` to

```
[DataMember(Name="ipAddress")]
public string IPAddress ( get; set; }
```

Instead, it should be

```
[DataMember(Name="ipAddress")]
public string[] IPAddress ( get; set; }
```